# VirtualBox: How to access virtual host on VM from host?

Tags: apache2, virtualbox, virtualhost

How to access from the host the Apache virtual domain created on virtual machine.

Settings of the VM on VirtualBox:

- VM ubuntu/precise32 on VirtualBox created with vagrantfile from [How to setup a LAMP development environment in Vagrant by Sanchit Jain Rasiya](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/vagrant-ubuntu-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp/)
- installed Apache/2.2.22
- installed Lynx browser
- Virtual Host  /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com

  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
      ServerName example.com
      DocumentRoot /home/vagrant/www/example.com
          
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          
      ErrorLog "/home/vagrant/www/example.com/logs/example.com-error.log"
      CustomLog "/home/vagrant/www/example.com/logs/example.com-access.log" combined

From the browser on the host machine I can access VM's `localhost` as `http://192.168.205.10/index.html`
How can I access VM's example.com?

On the host's `/etc/hosts` I have added line for example.com

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.2   tmp.loc
127.0.0.3   temp.loc
192.168.205.10  example.com
```

When I try `http://example.com/mj.html` I get the `404 Not Found` page from *Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80*

On the virtual machine I can access  page with the Lynx

```
lynx http://example.com/mj.html
```

This is noted in the `/home/vagrant/www/example.com/logs/example.com-access.log` file as

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2016:15:53:49 +0000] "GET /mj.html HTTP/1.0" 200 344 "-" "Lynx/2.8.8dev.9 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/2.12.14"
```

But when I try to access example.com from the host there are no logs neither in access.log nor  /home/vagrant/www/example.com/logs/example.com-error.log

There are no logs in the host's Server files /opt/lampp/logs/access_log and /opt/lampp/logs/error_log

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.2.2       example.com
```

On Windows (VBox) C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
10.0.2.2 localhost
10.0.2.2 example.com
```

Then just reboot your VBox Windows and type in browser (on Windows):
http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I've been trying to access my drupal project from my virtualbox vm but it is not working. One of the solutions I found on the Internet is using the outer keyword in your hosts file in the VM.

The following works fine for me:

1. In your host machine (let's say a ubuntu) type: ifconfig, and get the
   inet address of wlan0 (example: 192.168.1.15)
2. Add this address to the host file in your virtualobox machine and use the outer keyword

   ```
   [192.168.1.15 outer]
   ```

Now you can access your localhost from your virtualbox browser by typing the address of your wlan0 (ex: 192.168.1.15).

- If you need to access a specific port on your host add the port number to
  the address example 192.168.1.15:8001